# How to make wxPython work?

Tags: python, wxpython

I have installed wxPython2.8 for windows 7 64 bit, however when I run their simple hello world program, nothing happen, no windows are shown. The proram just stuck in app.MainLoop(). Does anybody has the same problem or know how to make it work?

```
import wx

app = wx.App(False)  # Create a new app, don't redirect stdout/stderr to a window.
frame = wx.Frame(None, wx.ID_ANY, "Hello World") # A Frame is a top-level window.
frame.Show(True)     # Show the frame.
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: It works for me on Windows 7, Python 2.7 (32 bits), wxPython 2.8.

Comment: Thanks, I figure out that the issue is Pyscripter's remote engine that prevents my wxpython programs to work correctly, not wxPython itself.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Duc's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/713711/duc) comment, the problem is not with wxPython, but rather with the remote engine of PyScripter. This remote engine can sometimes prevent wxPython programs from running correctly. The remote engine can sometimes [prevent the display of output](https://code.google.com/p/pyscripter/wiki/RemoteEngines).

Comment: See [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139075/187647) for why I'm answering an old post.